# Keeping a footer on screen in UICollectionView during an Add

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a standard FlowLayout UICollectionView (scrolling vertically, single section, fixed size items, but a variable number of columns (e.g. 2 in iphone landscape v 1 in horiz v 3 or 4 on ipad). I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController to manage the items displayed from Core Data.

I have an Add button in the footer supplementary to add a new item.  When the user presses the Add button, I naturally want to add an item, but then I want the Add button remain on the screen (scrolling up if necessary), so they can easily press it again.

I currently check in the addItem routine:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * footerInfo = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0 ]];
[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:footerInfo.frame animated:YES];
```

This works well, except that when the FRC adds the item on the next runloop, the collectionView then moves the footer down offscreen again.

I can't just add a extra row of height to the frame for two reasons: first, that expanded rect isn't on the controllerView yet, second: if it's not a new line, I don't need that space and it'll bounce back down unnecessarily.

I guess I could schedule a scroll check for a future time/runloop after the insertion is complete, but I was hoping there might be something cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple:  add the scroll check to the completion block of self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:completion: